# Why is it easier to render a mesh with potentially tens of thousands of vertices, UV mapping, materials, etc than it is to make an irregular collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, mesh, game-development

This question isn't about how I should make my colliders in engine, but rather why people will raise performance concerns when talking about mesh colliders when it seems to be a normal thing to render a high-poly mesh. Why are colliders relegated to being simple 3d objects like cuboids, spheres, or capsules while the meshes they represent can be rendered in extremely high detail? Is it that graphics processors are just more powerful and the graphics pipeline is more optimized?

Comment: Colliders are not used for their graphical representations, they are used in complex math functions for determining collisions and overlapping.  Keeping these simpler makes the resulting maths simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some types of collision checks, such as simple ray traces for checking sight lines or bullet trajectories, actually can use high resolution meshes as long as those meshes have a spatial acceleration structure.

To some degree it is indeed relevant that GPUs are very powerful and there is no (common) hardware that focuses specifically on collision checks. However, collision also has a unique problem that as more detail is added, the amount of work scales with the amount of detail *squared*. If you have an object with 100 triangles colliding with another object that has 100 triangles, you potentially have to do 100 * 100 = 10000 collision checks. You can alleviate this with spatial partitioning if the objects are rigid, but that adds complexity. Physics objects that come to rest on top of ground collision (or another physics object) tend to end up with one of their surfaces flat against the ground (or other object), so in this common case you have to check all of the overlapping collision detail along that surface. Often the world geometry is *relatively* high res, so the objects that collide with the world have to sacrifice detail to keep that multiplier low.

For some types of collision, like player collision, there's another multiplier: as the collision geometry becomes more complex, the code that moves the player has to be smarter about dealing with tiny bumps and slopes so that collision doesn't feel "sticky". This can require more collision checks (or traces), so in a way there's almost a *cubed* relationship between collision detail and work. (Although again this is a simplification.)

Another reason is simply that it's not worth it. If you can get good gameplay with simple collision shapes, why not save the processing power for other things? In fact, sometimes simple shapes like spheres, capsules and cylinders are preferable because they can glide around more smoothly.